# Intrusive DevExpress Dialogue

Tags: visual-studio-2012, devexpress

I must first say I have had a ticket open on DevExpress support for several days now with no resolution. I thought maybe other developers here have the same problem, and maybe even a solution.

While using the 30 Day Trial, whenever a DevExpress component is create, or something, an immovable and large dialogue pops up on the screen, on the same thread (I think) that created the component. If there is an error or breakpoint in the code that triggered that dialogue, all is lost. The debugger is unresponsive, and the evaluation dialogue is unresponsive. To make matters worse, it always appears centre screen, obscuring the error message, as in the image attached. My only recourse is to restart VS, but what then? The same debugging sequence has the same effect again. At this rate I will need 300, not 30, days to evaluate the product.[image: Figure 1]

EDIT: I have posted a ticket at http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q534381, and they are working on it.

Comment: I have a full winforms licence on my machine and have had this. I found the only way to get shot of it was to uninstall Devexpress and re-install.

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience, a [Trial Screen](https://www.devexpress.com/issue=A705) is expected when using a Trial Version.
However, the mentioned issue is not a proper behavior and should be changed.
In any case, I believe that only DevExpress support can assist you with this issue and put you on the right track in the most effective manner.

If you has already posted an inquiry to the support, share the corresponding link here.
Once you get a valuable response from the support team, post a new answer here and [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) to close the SO issue.

Comment: Yes, of course a trial screen is expected, just not a deadlocking one. I have posted a ticket at http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q534381, and they are working on it.